# Geometry node, distribute a specific number of points not a specific density

Tags: particles, weight-painting, geometry-nodes

I've not been able to find a clear answer to this with my searching.

Put simply I want to distribute points over a spherical surface using geometry nodes according to a vertex weight paint texture. However, I need the final number of points to be a specific number of points regardless of the size of the sphere (let's say 2500). As far as I can tell there is no way to specify the final number of points to be distributed, I only have control over a number/square meter value which means the number of points drastically increases as I increase the size of the sphere.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can trim the number of points by deleting unneeded points. And if you want to keep chaotic distribution of points on any surface you should to use modulo math operator. This give you ability to keep not **points with index less then N** but **every N point** in the bunch of points.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can trim the number of points with a delete geometry node?

[image]

Comment: you could use that multiply node to first aproximate your max value -maybe enable statics under viewport overlays- so you will trim just a few points... or try the other posted answer wich removes every other point